# Is my list comprehension not correct?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find an integer in a list that occurs an odd number of times. Below is the solution I'm trying to implement but I'm getting the following: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

I don't understand why my list comprehension isn't returning anything. If I understand the error, there's an iteration going on somewhere that I'm not seeing?

```
from collections import Counter

def find_it(seq):
    new_seq = Counter()
    odd_appearances = None
    for i in seq:
        new_seq[i] += 1
    for v in new_seq.values():
        if v % 2 == 1:
            odd_appearances = v
    return [k for k, v in new_seq.items() if odd_appearances in v]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object `v`, as a value of the `new_seq` counter, is an integer.  This expression:

```
odd_appearances in v
```

attempts to iterate `v` to check for membership, and as you've noticed an argument of type 'int' is not iterable.  So that is the problematic part of the list comprehension.  A more Pythonic way to use the `collections.Counter` class would be like this:

```
def find_it(seq):
    new_seq = Counter(seq)
    return [k for k, v in new_seq.items() if v % 2 == 1]
```